# Is there a solution to release a PHP web application from a phar file?

Tags: php, phar

I'm looking for a solution (if such an exists) to release a PHP web application from .phar analogically to Java's WAR file.

Requirements:

- compiling source into a package
- automatically unpack public files on release
- support pre/post install hooks
- optionally have a web interface like TomCat

I know it's relatively easy to build it but I was wondering is there a ready solution for that?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the phar file directly ? What do you gain by "unpacking" the files ?

Comment: How would you access assets (images, scripts, etc) from a PHAR file though a web server without any performance penalty?

Comment: How bad is the performance penalty? Do you have any numbers you can share?

Comment: What about using `PEAR` packages and the `PEAR` installer instead of `phar`? `PEAR` supports the file role `www` what will install the files in a (configurable) web directory. Also `composer` should do the job. (maybe preferably)

Comment: Ignoring the performance can one access an image file via a web server from a phar file without any PHP involvement? I'm not aware it's possible.

Comment: PEAR is horrible, I would go for the composer

Answer (score 2):

You can access static files form phar files easily, but there is some performance penalty involved.

See my [phar benchmark blog post](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-phar-files.htm#benchmark) for more info.